# How can I set up OpenVPN to accept more than 60 connections?

Tags: openvpn, configuration

Greetings!

We're using OpenVPN and today hit an unexpected connection limit of 60 - even though max-clients is set to the source code default 1024.

Server log:

> Tue Dec 21 13:49:41 2010 MULTI: new incoming connection would exceed maximum number of clients (60)

We're slowly adding new clients to the VPN and expect to hit 200 some time next year, 
**if** we can get it working.

We're running the server on a Win2003 R2. OpenVPN 2.0.9 Server config as follows:

> local 192.168.10.211
>   port 1195
>   proto tcp
>   dev tun
>   dev-node OpenVPN_Vision
>   ca vision_ca.crt
>   cert vision_server.crt
>   key vision_server.key  # This file should be kept secret
>   dh vision_dh1024.pem
>   server 192.168.211.0 255.255.255.0
>   ifconfig-pool-persist vision_ipp.txt
>   ;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100
>   ;client-to-client
>   keepalive 10 120
>   comp-lzo
>   ;max-clients 100  # Default in source code is 1024
>   persist-key
>   persist-tun
>   status openvpn-status-vision.log
>   log         vision.log
>   verb 3

I would greatly appreciate any help or input on this one. Thanks!
Best regards,
Robin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be your problem:
https://forums.openvpn.net/topic2445.html

> It looks like the 2000 max_clients setting is getting overridden in
>   we_init and getting set to WSA_MAXIMUM_WAIT_EVENTS, which is 64, minus
>   4. My understanding is this is a hardcoded limit built into the windows kernel. The 60 client limit is determined by subtracting
>   extra_events (set to BASE_N_EVENTS, or 4) from it.

Basically, run it in udp mode and you can go over 60. The limit is in windows and openvpn isn't to blame.

Comment: Sirex, I'm not blaming anyone. Well, perhaps Windows. ;-) Your answer is not really satisfying, but still seems to be the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: Yea, it's not ideal, but the limit is hard coded into windows :-(

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it through any type of router/firewall?  That could have it's own limit.

Comment: Good point! Well, I already eliminated those as possible reasons, but I should have said that in my question. Thanks!